# get server-display-nickname from every User on Discord - Python Api Bot

Tags: python, api, discord, bots, member

Sorry, my english is not that good.
I have a problem: my own discord bot in python should return all members (.nick, not the discord login-in username) on a specific discord server. But at the moment my discord bot, on a normal chanel (text-chanel, the bot has all available permissions), returns me only an empty list. Only in a Voice-Chanel it returns a members-list.

So Jungs, für unsere Deutschen: wir brauchen eine Liste aller Members mit ihren jeweiligen Nicknamen auf einem Discord-Server. Wir haben bereits versucht einen Member zu erstellen, jedoch klappt es nicht so ganz, da  wir entweder keinen gültigen Member erzeugen (Rückgabewert = None) oder kein Nick angezeigt wird und wir nur einen User rausbekommen. Problem ist auch, sobald wir versuchen über Text-Channel die Members abzurufen, bekommen wir nur eine leere Liste aller Members, aber innerhalb eines Voice-Channels bekommen wir eine gültige Liste aller Members, die sich zu diesem Zeitpunkt in dem Voice-Channel befinden.

Sorry, erklären ist auch nicht unsere Stärke. Danke für Eure Verständnis!

Comment: Can you show us the code for the Discord bot that you're talking about?  We can't help you if you don't show us what you're doing in your code.  Also, please pick one language or another for your post...preferably English for this site.

Answer (score 1):

A list consisting of strings with users nicknames if they exist, else user names is easy to create with

```py
names = [x.display_name for x in guild.members]
```

in case you want more data with it, you can do something one the lines of

```py
data = [{"id": x.id, "name": x.name, "nick": x.nick} for x in guild.members]
```

which would give you a list of dictionaries containing the user name, id and nick (if exists, else that will be `None`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you tried to use .users[i].name?
for eg.

```
client = discord.Client()
for i in range(len(client.users)):
    print(client.users[i].name)
```